# How to increment in time?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, stopwatch

I am creating a stopwatch type application. I've used a label to display time. When application starts, the label is initialized to '00:00:00' and I want to increment its time by every 1 second.

I am trying to accomplish this job by using timer.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am getting you right, it may surely work. Set initial label Text as "00:00:00". Set timer interval as 1000.

```
private void btnStartWatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void btnPauseWatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}

int i = 1;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = dt.AddSeconds(i).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    i++;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that nothing guarantees that your `timer1_Tick` method will be called exactly every second. The only thing Windows guarantees is that *at least* one second will elapse between calls to the timer tick function. So, if you let this run for a day while you're still using your computer, it will probably read a bit slow. The correct way to calculate the elapsed time is to take the *current* time and *subtract* the start time, giving the amount of elapsed time between the start and now.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Good point. But if its a stop watch as asked in the question, this approach may work perfect.

Answer (score 3):

In your timer get the system time so your timer must be with very small interval like 200ms. To calculate your time just calculate the currentTime - startTIme in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`TimeSpan` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Something like:

```
TimeSpan current = new TimeSpan(0);

// In your update loop:

current += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a timer on one of my apps.

```
private int _seconds;

public string TimeDisplay
{
    get
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, _seconds );
        return string.Format("{0,2:00}:{1,2:00}:{2,2:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is have your timer_tick even increment _seconds and NotifyPropertyChanged() if you're binding to it.  Either way, TimeDisplay will have your result.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that nothing guarantees that your `timer1_Tick` event method will be called exactly every second. The only thing Windows guarantees is that *at least* one second will elapse between calls to the timer tick function. So, if you let this run for a day while you're still using your computer, it will probably read a bit slow. The correct way to calculate the elapsed time is to take the *current* time and *subtract* the start time, giving the amount of elapsed time between the start and now.

Answer (score 0):

i hope understand.

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

      Timer1.Interval = 1000;
      Timer1.Start();
}
private void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        this.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh/mm/ss");

 }
```

Regards

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString();
It will set the timer to the system time. I've mentioned in my query that I am creating a stopwatch type application. It should start from 00:00:00

Comment: @MuhammadAliDildar , Can't you calculate the difference between sys time & your startuptime?

Comment: @L.B: its not needed. better to change your approach. it may become very confusing

Comment: @rapsalands I don't propose any approach. It was an answer to `It will set the timer to the system time`